# Alternative for Wifi manager removeNetwork() in Android Q. New Api WifiNetworkSuggestion only removing suggestion

Tags: android

Alternative for Wifi manager removeNetwork() in Android Q. New Api WifiNetworkSuggestion only removing suggestion not configured wifi network from Mobile

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Android Q doesn't allow to removeNetwork() anymore. It's a part of Google's privacy improvements.